# PHP: Object A extends Object B, do they share a constructor?

Tags: php, inheritance

In PHP, when Object B extends Object A, why does Object's B instantiation not automatically trigger the `__construct()` in Object A?

It seems strange that I have two duplicate the entirety of Object A's construct function in Object B's construct function. Am I making a mistake? Or misusing inheritance?

Comment: Constructors play by the regular rules of method inheritance and overloading.

Comment: Please read the manual page about OO in PHP, before writing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't implement a new __construct method, the constructor from class A is automatically called. If you want to create a new constructor in B and also call the old from class A, you have to call `parent::__construct(yourparams,...)`

Comment: Should I be setting the constructors as static functions? At the moment I just do `function __construct`. I don't even declare public or private.

Comment: No. Constructors will be called when you instantiate the object. `$a = new A();` will call A's constructor.

Comment: There's no such thing as a static constructor!  If you don't declare them to have a visibility then they're implicitly public.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to duplicate the code.

If B's constructor is not defined, then it will take A's constructor.

If it is, then you need to chain the construct call back to A, something like this.

```
class A {

    function __construct(...) {
        //do something
    }
}

class B extends A {

    function __construct(...) {
        parent::__construct(...);
        //do something more
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the subclass doesn't have an explicit constructor then the superclass constructor is implicitly run.

If the subclass does have an explicit constructor then it overrides the constructor in the superclass, so you can completely change the subclass instantiation behaviour if necessary.

If you want to add additional instantiation behaviour to a subclass but still want to keep the superclass behaviour too, then you should do the following:

```
public function __construct ($arg) {
    parent::__construct ($arg);
    // Additional construction logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks GordonM, how comes `parent::__construct ($arg)` appears to be a static function, but we define constructors using `public function __construct()`?

Comment: That's just the calling convention for them.  You'd have to ask the PHP developers why.

Comment: Ok cool, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some concept.

Comment: why don't you make it a real SO question instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need fo call parent::__construct() from your child class' constructor as the parent constructor isn't implicitly called.

Take a look at this

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: I should say that the above is only true if the child declares a constructor, but I see its covered by GordonM anyway